# How is Normalizr used properly with 3 a merged Array of Objects?

Tags: reactjs, redux, normalization, normalizr

I'm trying to get my head around normalizing my arrays of objects with Normalizr, but do not get the right, or expected result.

These are 3 arrays of objects:

```
const assistants = [
  {
    id: 1,
    first_name: "Nickolas",
    last_name: "Seamans",
    phone: "+62 949 597 4013",
    email: "nseamans0@dentistcompanybvt.com"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    first_name: "Peri",
    last_name: "Helversen",
    phone: "+51 886 232 9275",
    email: "phelversen1@dentistcompanybvt.com"
  }
];
```

and

```
const clients = [
  {
    id: 1,
    first_name: "Mona",
    last_name: "Shakelade",
    phone: "+63 475 243 2059",
    email: "mshakelade0@sourceforge.net",
    date_of_birth: "26/01/1987",
    status: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    first_name: "Dario",
    last_name: "Aizikovitz",
    phone: "+33 454 959 7355",
    email: "daizikovitz1@buzzfeed.com",
    date_of_birth: "16/08/1999",
    status: null
  }
];
```

and

```
const dentists = [
  {
    id: 1,
    first_name: "Tessa",
    last_name: "Iiannone",
    phone: "+234 325 319 4277",
    email: "tiiannone0@dentistcompanybvt.com"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    first_name: "Kennett",
    last_name: "Pedreschi",
    phone: "+48 204 144 9885",
    email: "kpedreschi1@dentistcompanybvt.com"
  }
];
```

and I merge them with:

```
import assistants from "../data/assistants";
import dentists from "../data/dentists";
import clients from "../data/clients";

const users = {
  dentists: dentists,
  assistants: assistants,
  clients: clients
};
```

so that the outcome of a console.log(users) is:

```
{dentists: Array(2), assistants: Array(2), clients: Array(2)}
assistants: (2) [{…}, {…}]
clients: (2) [{…}, {…}]
dentists: (2) [{…}, {…}]
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I have fabricated this normalizr steps:

```
const dentistsList = new schema.Entity("dentists", {}, { idAttribute: "id" });
const dentistsSchema = [dentistsList];
const assistantsList = new schema.Entity(
  "assistants",
  {},
  { idAttribute: "id" }
);
const assistantsSchema = [assistantsList];
const clientsList = new schema.Entity("clients", {}, { idAttribute: "id" });
const clientsSchema = [clientsList];

const usersSchema = new schema.Entity("users", {
  clients: clientsSchema,
  assistants: assistantsSchema,
  dentists: dentistsSchema
});

const usersArraySchema = [usersSchema];

const normalizedArray = normalize(users, [usersArraySchema]);
```

Now my outcome with a console.log(normalizedArray) is:

```
{entities: {…}, result: Array(3)}
entities:
users: {1: {…}, 2: {…}}
[[Prototype]]: Object
result: Array(3)
0: (2) [1, 2]
1: (2) [1, 2]
2: (2) [1, 2]
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

so where are my assistants and dentists went? They are counted separately in the 'result' section though...

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the solution was not that hard, but that is always the case once you know it. The following notation did the trick:

```
const assistant = new schema.Entity("assistants");
const dentist = new schema.Entity("dentists");
const client = new schema.Entity("clients");
const userSchema = {
  assistants: [assistant],
  dentists: [dentist],
  clients: [client]
};
const normalizedUsers = normalize(users, userSchema);
```

the outcome of a console.log(normalisedUsers) is now:

```
{entities: {…}, result: {…}}
entities:
assistants: {201: {…}, 202: {…}}
clients: {1: {…}, 2: {…}}
dentists: {101: {…}, 102: {…}}
[[Prototype]]: Object
result:
assistants: (2) [201, 202]
clients: (2) [1, 2]
dentists: (2) [101, 102]
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

I hope one could benefit from my solution sharing.